# Ionic serve stopped working with error: 'Node Sass does not yet support your current environment'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic-native

Ionic serve used to work perfectly fine and suddenly I went to run my app and I keep getting this:

```
Danas-MacBook-Air:myFinalApp DanaCarlin$ ionic serve
Error: Node Sass does not yet support your current environment: OS X 
64-bit with Unsupported runtime (59)
For more information on which environments are supported please see:
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v4.5.3
at module.exports (/Users/DanaCarlin/MyFinalApp/node_modules/node-
sass/lib/binding.js:13:13)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/Users/DanaCarlin/MyFinalApp/node_modules/node-
sass/lib/index.js:14:35)
at Module._compile (module.js:641:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:652:10)
at Module.load (module.js:560:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:503:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:495:3)
at Module.require (module.js:585:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> 
(/Users/DanaCarlin/MyFinalApp/node_modules/@ionic/app-
scripts/dist/core/bundle-components.js:6:16)
```

I don't think I have changed anything. Could someone please help me out! Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling node modules?

Comment: Hi, yes I did but nothing changed. I even uninstalled and reinstalled and it is saying the same thing.

Comment: check https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1764

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to rebuild node-sass :

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```